# Commit a single attribute value and not whole transaction

Tags: java, sql, oracle, concurrency

I have a java program which does many interaction with DB (oracle) which is started by a single transaction. I need to update a column,say Y of some table say X, and that this should be committed but not the whole transaction.

Why I need that, is because when that java program to do some stuff and if fails somewhere then all the things done by java program is rolled back, but when I do commit in that java program itself after update the column in table X then it will also commit the things done till now and I won't be able to enjoy the rollback thing for whole transaction.

The value of that column is needed to handle concurrent program invocation.

Comment: Look in to Oracle's support for SAVEPOINTs.  You can then open a transaction, do some stuff, mark a save point, do more stuff, and on an error decide which save point to roll back to.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm Refer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to update a column,say Y of some table say X, and that this should be committed but not the whole transaction.

You can perform the update of X in an [autonomous transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i36056).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateXofY(
  in_id IN X.ID%TYPE,
  in_y  IN X.Y%TYPE
)
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  UPDATE X
  SET   Y  = in_y
  WHERE id = in_id;
  COMMIT;
END updateXofY;
/
```

Once you call the procedure it will update column Y of table X and `COMMIT` the autonomous transaction without committing the calling transaction.

The drawback of this is that the autonomous transaction is `COMMIT`ted so that if you `ROLLBACK` the main transaction then this will not `ROLLBACK` the autonomous transaction (since it is autonomous).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just start another transaction to do the "inner" work. Keep the current transaction running and use the new transaction to do the extra piece of work.

Unless if the outer transaction fails you want to roll back the inner transaction as well. In which case I think you need nested transactions.

Comment: To my knowledge, nested transactions don't roll back one level of nesting, they all go at once.  Instead, as far as I just read briefly, Oracle supports SAVEPOINTs and at a ROLLBACK you can choose a save point to rollback to.  If you don't choose which save point to roll back to, all transactions roll back.

Answer (score 0):

Autonomous transactions are good advice. However, you could also open a second connection in your Java program. Handle the updates/commits in one connection and the main transaction in the other.

Answer (score 0):

With naked JDBC, a new Connection as mentioned by Martin Schapendonk is the way to go.

With Spring the [Propagation#REQUIRES_NEW](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) on the [Transactional annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) would be available. Similarly, with EJB one could use [TransactionAttributeType#REQUIRES_NEW](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW).

Answer (score -1):

The reason behind an transaction is too be atomic. Therefore there is no general way to do this but save the value and update in another transaction.

Comment: A quick google tells me that Oracle support save points.  Which should allow a partial rollback?  *(Although I'm not 100% clear if that's what the OP wants.)*

Comment: Savepoints just jump back to the last one in the transaction, Right? I've understood OP's Question as if he wants to just Keep the data and discard everything else in the Transaction.